# how to get a value from a map (made of structs) if I only know a parameter of the value

Tags: c++

I have this struct:

```c
struct pos_struct {
    float last_seen;
    array<int, 2> last_pos;
};
```

then, I have this map:

```c
map<int, pos_struct> my_map;
```

In a certain point of the code, I get the position, for example [317, 203].

I want to know the `last_seen` of this position. How could I do that? (the value of the position is unique)

Comment: If you need to get the `int` associated with `pos_struct` you need to search the whole map. If this case happens you are probably using the wrong type of data structure.

Comment: What are the keys of your map?

Comment: Maybe there are more data structures that I don't know. But I'm pretty sure I am using the correct for my case (actually the struct is larger but I post it this way to simplify). 
Having this specific case, the only way is to search the whole map? How would be the most efficient way to do it then?

Comment: The keys of the map are identifiers. I use OpenCV to detect an object, the int is the ID of the object, and pos_struct are the properties of the object

Comment: One idea is to keep two maps, one with an `int` key, the other with `pos_struct` as the key and the `int` of the other map as its value. Another is maybe you actually want `last_pos` to be the key, and `last_seen` as the value.